# Can we chain the ternary operator in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-operator

Can we chain the ternary operator in Python? We can do it for multiple `if` conditions in Java. Can that be done in Python too?

Comment: For one if else condition it works fine like below :
a = "4.6"
value = "newValue" if a=="4.6" else "oldValue"

But if I put 2 conditions, the pycharm editor gives error 

value = "newValue" if a=="4.1" elif a=="4.6"  else "oldValue"

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: [Conditional expressions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=conditional%20expression#conditional-expressions) are expressions like any other. Since they have the lowest priority of all operators, you can nest a conditional expression in another without writing parentheses:  `this if x else that if y else other` is the same as `this if x else (that if y else other)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiple nested ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636514/python-multiple-nested-ternary-expression)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
x = 'x' if 1<0 else 'y' if 0<1 else 'z'
```